# PHP: How to escape comment symbol for parse_ini_file / parse_ini_file_string functions

Tags: php, comments, ini

I have ini file option:

```
test="hello;wordl"
```

If you use INI_SCANNER_RAW argument in parse_ini_file function then it returns:

```
[test]="hello
```

because (;) is a comment symbol.

I tried to use (\) escape symbol before (;) but result was the same. Do you have any idea about how to escape the comment symbol?

Comment: It seems like that [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51094) [have been fixed](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=fed5923dbc849659321a4f9aa96634ddd1655229) in recent versions of php.